# handling several textboxes in windows Phone using loops

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In Desktop windows programming we can make an array of window handles and assign the hadles of edit windows to this array and then we can use a loop to extract and manage the data from edit boxes. In window Phone (Since I'm a beginner, as far as I know) you can access a text box's input text using its name. I have several text boxes and I want to extract their text using loops in pagename.xaml.cs using C#. How to do this in a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clarify your question.

To assign data or extract data

```
  foreach(UIElement ele in YourGridName.Children){
        if(ele is TextBox){
            (ele as TextBox).Text = "What ever you want";
            //Or
            String text = (ele as TextBox).Text;
        }
    }
```

if you are trying to do it by name you can do the following

```
foreach(UIElement ele in YourGridName.Children){
    if(ele is TextBox){
        Switch((ele as TextBox).Name){
           case("TextBox1"):

           break;
           case("TextBox2"):

           break;
         }
    }
}
```